# How to determine if a set contains another set in Python

Tags: python-2.7

How can I check whether one set is contained within another set if the number of significant figures doesn't quite match? For example, I want to know if set s1 is contained in set s2 (I want it to be):

```
>>> s1 = set(['1', '2', '3'])
>>> s2 = set(['1.000', '2.000', '3.000', '4.0000'])
>>> s1 in s2
False
```

but since

```
>>> '1' in '1.000'
True
>>> '2' in '2.000'
True
>>> '3' in '3.0000'
True
>>> '4' in '4.000'
True
```

I don't understand why Python does not consider set s1 to be in set s2, since clearly it considers each element of s1 to be contained in an element of set s2.

Comment: Do you *really* want to be doing string comparisons to tell if your numbers are equal? `"4" in "3.14"` is also `True`, but I suspect that's not a result you want with your sets. I'd suggest rounding all your numbers to some precision (as floats or `decimal.Decimal` instances, perhaps), then comparing them for equality (which you can do with a set comparison or intersection).

Comment: Thanks @Blckknght, good point. Could you please show me how exactly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need a mixture of [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
>>> all(any(s1_i in s2_i for s2_i in s2) for s1_i in s1)
True
```

`all()` makes sure that each item in s1 is contained in s2 by your rules.  Those rules are defined programmatically with `any()`.  It sees if the item is contained in any of the items in `s2`.

Since both `all()` and `any()` are short-circuiting, this is a very efficient way of finding the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure an O(N**2) solution is well described as "efficient". Set comparisons are generally O(N), so it may be a lot slower than rounding the set values (which will be O(N)) and then intersecting.

Comment: This completely answered my question, but I really like @Blckknght's point and associated solution. My compromise was to keep this as the accepted answer, but to vote up the other.

Answer (score 5):

Using string operations to work on numbers is a bad idea. Instead, you should convert your numbers to a numeric type, such as `float` or `decimal.Decimal` so they behave like actual numbers. You can then round them to an appropriate precision and compare them (or sets of them) in the usual way. If you're only concerned about trailing zeros, you don't even need to round.

For instance, if you think two digits of precision is good enough (and you don't mind that `float`s are binary values that may not be able to exactly represent the decimal numbers you entered):

```
s1 = set(['1', '2', '3'])
s2 = set(['1.000', '2.000', '3.000', '4.0000'])

rounded_s1 = set(round(float(i), 2) for i in s1)
rounded_s2 = set(round(float(i), 2) for i in s2)

print(rounded_s1.issubset(rounded_s2))
```

Comment: It should be faster to use a set comprehension rather than a generator expression with the `set` function.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the are not equal because '1' is not equal '1.000' as you can see '1' is part of '1.000'.They are different characters
Try this

```
s1 = set(['1.000', '2.000', '3.000'])
s2 = set(['1.000', '2.000', '3.000', '4.0000'])
print (s1.issubset(s2))
if('1'=='1.000'):
   print ("ok")
```

This is the right one without the Single Quote

```
  s1 = set([1,2,3])
  s2 = set([1.000, 2.000, 3.000, 4.0000])
  print (s1.issubset(s2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
all([f'{item}.000' in s2 for item in s1])
```

If it returns True, then S1 is contained in S2. the `f'{item}.000'` is to convert the string as you need, to match with S2, because they are a little different.

Regards